# Checked exceptions thrown from within lambda expressions

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-8, checked-exceptions

Can you please explain why checked exceptions have to be caught from within lambda expressions? In other words, why does the following code not compile...

```
public void doSomething(ObjectInputStream istream) throws IOException {
  // The read method throws an IOException.
  IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> someList.add(read(istream)));
}
```

but this one will?

```
public void doSomething(ObjectInputStream istream) throws IOException {
  IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> {
    try {
      // The read method throws an IOException.
      someList.add(read(istream));
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
      // Callee has to handle checked exception, not caller.
    }
  });
}
```

It seems like the callee now has to handle any checked exceptions that are thrown and not the caller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue isn't the lambda expression, it's the interface it's implementing. Remember, a lambda expression is basically just shorthand for an anonymous class that implements a given interface.

In this case, `forEach` takes a `java.util.function.Consumer<T>`:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
    ...
}
```

Note that `accept` is not declared to throw anything. This means that no implementation of it can throw anything; not a named class, not an anonymous class, and not a lambda.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that your `read` method throws `IOException`.

The signature of `IntStream.forEach` is [`forEach(IntConsumer action)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#forEach-java.util.function.IntConsumer-), where `IntConsumer` has a `void accept(int value)` method. In that context your lambda expression `i -> someList.add(read(istream))` is equivalent to:

```
public class IntConsumerImplementation implements IntConsumer {
   ObjectInputStream istream;
   public void accept(int i) {
      someList.add(read(istream));
   };
}
```

which doesn't compile because `read` throws a checked exception.

On the other hand, lambda expressions **may** throw checked exceptions if the functional interface defines them (which is **not** the case for consumers or other `java.util` functional interfaces).

Suppose the following made up example:

```
 @FunctionalInterface
 public interface NotAnIntConsumer {
    public void accept(int i) throws IOException;
 }
```

Now the following compiles:

```
forEach(NotAnIntConsumer naic) { ... }
doSomething(ObjectInputStream istream) throws IOException {
   IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> someList.add(read(istream)));
}
```